# Update publish date on gatsby blog

Tags: gatsby

I need a bit of direction with my site. I want to update the publish dates on my blogs as I edit them. The date is a part of the slug but is not a part of the finished URL. My urls are wesite.com/blog which is good. Im just not sure were google is picking up the date. I don't see it in the meta data.

But when I change that date, it will not complete a build. It fails, and I have to revert. The other option is not to provide the date to google, to begin with. I think I can remove it from gatsby-config, but I'm not sure how to verify it. I don't show the publish date on the blog page, but it is in the meta and appears in the SERP. Did anyone run into this before?

```
     require("dotenv").config();
const config = require("./content/meta/config");
const transformer = require("./src/utils/algolia");

const query = `{
  allMarkdownRemark( filter: { fields: { slug: { ne: null } } }) {
    edges {
      node {
        objectID: fileAbsolutePath
        fields {
          slug
        }
        internal {
          content
        }
        frontmatter {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`;

const queries = [
  {
    query,
    transformer: ({ data }) => {
      return data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.reduce(transformer, []);
    }
  }
];

module.exports = {
  // pathPrefix: config.pathPrefix,
  siteMetadata: {
    title: config.siteTitle,
    description: config.siteDescription,
    siteUrl: config.siteUrl,
    algolia: {
      appId: process.env.ALGOLIA_APP_ID ? process.env.ALGOLIA_APP_ID : "",
      searchOnlyApiKey: process.env.ALGOLIA_SEARCH_ONLY_API_KEY
        ? process.env.ALGOLIA_SEARCH_ONLY_API_KEY
        : "",
      indexName: process.env.ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME ? process.env.ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME : ""
    },
    facebook: {
      appId: process.env.FB_APP_ID ? process.env.FB_APP_ID : ""
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-jsx`, // the plugin's code is inserted directly to gatsby-node.js and gatsby-ssr.js files
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-jsx-postcss`, // as above
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-layout`,
      options: {
        component: require.resolve(`./src/layouts/`)
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-algolia`,
      options: {
        appId: process.env.ALGOLIA_APP_ID ? process.env.ALGOLIA_APP_ID : "",
        apiKey: process.env.ALGOLIA_ADMIN_API_KEY ? process.env.ALGOLIA_ADMIN_API_KEY : "",
        indexName: process.env.ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME ? process.env.ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME : "",
        queries,
        chunkSize: 10000 // default: 1000
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images/`
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/content/posts/`,
        name: "posts"
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/content/pages/`,
        name: "pages"
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `parts`,
        path: `${__dirname}/content/parts/`
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
          `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 800,
              backgroundColor: "transparent"
            }
          },
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-adsense`,
            options: {
              googleAdClientId: "***********",
              head: true // Optional
            }
          },
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe`,
            options: {
              wrapperStyle: `margin-bottom: 2em`
            }
          },
          `gatsby-remark-prismjs`,
          `gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files`,
          `gatsby-remark-smartypants`,
          {
            resolve: "gatsby-remark-emojis",
            options: {
              // Deactivate the plugin globally (default: true)
              active: true,
              // Add a custom css class
              class: "emoji-icon",
              // Select the size (available size: 16, 24, 32, 64)
              size: 64,
              // Add custom styles
              styles: {
                display: "inline",
                margin: "0",
                "margin-top": "1px",
                position: "relative",
                top: "5px",
                width: "25px"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-catch-links`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: config.manifestName,
        short_name: config.manifestShortName,
        start_url: config.manifestStartUrl,
        background_color: config.manifestBackgroundColor,
        theme_color: config.manifestThemeColor,
        display: config.manifestDisplay,
        icons: [
          {
            src: "/icons/icon-48x48.png",
            sizes: "48x48",
            type: "image/png"
          },
          {
            src: "/icons/icon-96x96.png",
            sizes: "96x96",
            type: "image/png"
          },
          {
            src: "/icons/icon-144x144.png",
            sizes: "144x144",
            type: "image/png"
          },
          {
            src: "/icons/icon-192x192.png",
            sizes: "192x192",
            type: "image/png"
          },
          {
            src: "/icons/icon-256x256.png",
            sizes: "256x256",
            type: "image/png"
          },
          {
            src: "/icons/icon-384x384.png",
            sizes: "384x384",
            type: "image/png"
          },
          {
            src: "/icons/icon-512x512.png",
            sizes: "512x512",
            type: "image/png"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`,
      options: {
        trackingId: process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-feed`,
      options: {
        query: `
          {
            site {
              siteMetadata {
                title
                description
                siteUrl
                site_url: siteUrl
              }
            }
          }
        `,
        feeds: [
          {
            serialize: ({ query: { site, allMarkdownRemark } }) => {
              return allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(edge => {
                return Object.assign({}, edge.node.frontmatter, {
                  description: edge.node.excerpt,
                  date: edge.node.fields.prefix,
                  url: site.siteMetadata.siteUrl + edge.node.fields.slug,
                  guid: site.siteMetadata.siteUrl + edge.node.fields.slug,
                  custom_elements: [{ "content:encoded": edge.node.html }]
                });
              });
            },
            query: `
              {
                allMarkdownRemark(
                  limit: 1000,
                  sort: { order: DESC, fields: [fields___prefix] },
                  filter: {
                    fields: {
                      prefix: { ne: null },
                      slug: { ne: null }
                    },
                    frontmatter: {
                      author: { ne: null }
                    }
                  }
                ) {
                  edges {
                    node {
                      excerpt
                      html
                      fields {
                        slug
                        prefix
                      }
                      frontmatter {
                        title
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            `,
            output: "/rss.xml"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-react-svg",
      options: {
        include: /svg-icons/
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

and the seo.js

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Helmet from "react-helmet";
import config from "../../../content/meta/config";

const Seo = props => {
  const { data, facebook } = props;
  const postTitle = ((data || {}).frontmatter || {}).title;
  const postDescription = ((data || {}).frontmatter || {}).description;
  const postCover = ((data || {}).frontmatter || {}).cover;
  const postSlug = ((data || {}).fields || {}).slug;

  const title = postTitle ? `${postTitle} - ${config.shortSiteTitle}` : config.siteTitle;
  const description = postDescription ? postDescription : config.siteDescription;
  const image = postCover ? postCover : config.siteImage;
  const url = config.siteUrl + config.pathPrefix + postSlug;

  return (
    <Helmet
      htmlAttributes={{
        lang: config.siteLanguage,
        prefix: "og: http://ogp.me/ns#"
      }}
    >
      {/* General tags */}
      <title>{title}</title>
      <meta name="description" content={description} />
      <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="17E3A9A27963C3889459D03DA4268BA3" />
      {/* OpenGraph tags */}
      <meta property="og:url" content={url} />
      <meta property="og:title" content={title} />
      <meta property="og:description" content={description} />
      <meta property="og:image" content={image} />
      <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
      <meta property="fb:app_id" content={facebook.appId} />
      {/* Twitter Card tags */}
      <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
      <meta
        name="twitter:creator"
        content={config.authorTwitterAccount ? config.authorTwitterAccount : ""}
      />
    </Helmet>
  );
};

Seo.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.object,
  facebook: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default Seo;
```

gatsby-node

```
//const webpack = require("webpack");
const _ = require("lodash");
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer").BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const path = require("path");
const Promise = require("bluebird");

const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`);

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, actions }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions;
  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const slug = createFilePath({ node, getNode });
    const fileNode = getNode(node.parent);
    const source = fileNode.sourceInstanceName;
    const separtorIndex = ~slug.indexOf("--") ? slug.indexOf("--") : 0;
    const shortSlugStart = separtorIndex ? separtorIndex + 2 : 0;

    if (source !== "parts") {
      createNodeField({
        node,
        name: `slug`,
        value: `${separtorIndex ? "/" : ""}${slug.substring(shortSlugStart)}`
      });
    }
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `prefix`,
      value: separtorIndex ? slug.substring(1, separtorIndex) : ""
    });
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `source`,
      value: source
    });
  }
};

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const postTemplate = path.resolve("./src/templates/PostTemplate.js");
    const pageTemplate = path.resolve("./src/templates/PageTemplate.js");
    const categoryTemplate = path.resolve("./src/templates/CategoryTemplate.js");

    let activeEnv = process.env.ACTIVE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
    console.log(`Using environment config: '${activeEnv}'`);

    resolve(
      graphql(
        `
          {
            allMarkdownRemark(
              filter: { fields: { slug: { ne: null } } }
              sort: { fields: [fields___prefix], order: DESC }
              limit: 1000
            ) {
              edges {
                node {
                  id
                  fields {
                    slug
                    prefix
                    source
                  }
                  frontmatter {
                    title
                    category
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        `
      ).then(result => {
        if (result.errors) {
          console.log(result.errors);
          reject(result.errors);
        }

        // Do not create draft post files in production.
        const items = result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.filter(item => {
          if (item.node.fields.source != "posts") return true;
          if (activeEnv != "production") return true;
          return item.node.fields.prefix.length > 0;
        });

        // Create category list
        const categorySet = new Set();
        items.forEach(edge => {
          const {
            node: {
              frontmatter: { category }
            }
          } = edge;

          if (category && category !== null) {
            categorySet.add(category);
          }
        });

        // Create category pages
        const categoryList = Array.from(categorySet);
        categoryList.forEach(category => {
          createPage({
            path: `/category/${_.kebabCase(category)}/`,
            component: categoryTemplate,
            context: {
              category
            }
          });
        });

        // Create posts
        const posts = items.filter(item => item.node.fields.source === "posts");
        posts.forEach(({ node }, index) => {
          const slug = node.fields.slug;
          const next = index === 0 ? undefined : posts[index - 1].node;
          const prev = index === posts.length - 1 ? undefined : posts[index + 1].node;
          const source = node.fields.source;

          createPage({
            path: slug,
            component: postTemplate,
            context: {
              slug,
              prev,
              next,
              source
            }
          });
        });

        // and pages.
        const pages = items.filter(item => item.node.fields.source === "pages");
        pages.forEach(({ node }) => {
          const slug = node.fields.slug;
          const source = node.fields.source;

          createPage({
            path: slug,
            component: pageTemplate,
            context: {
              slug,
              source
            }
          });
        });
      })
    );
  });
};

exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, actions }, options) => {
  switch (stage) {
    case `build-javascript`:
      actions.setWebpackConfig({
        plugins: [
          new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
            analyzerMode: "static",
            reportFilename: "./report/treemap.html",
            openAnalyzer: true,
            logLevel: "error",
            defaultSizes: "gzip"
          })
        ]
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: Your query doesn't include the date - you need to modify the query so that the date appears there (it's only in the slug and feed the way your code reads now)

Comment: Where are the dates? In addition, to check how you create the URLs of the posts, you need to provide the `gatsby-node.js` file.

Comment: Thanks I will add it